# Apply flow of $V$ to a segment of a curve, Do you get covariant derivative?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-analysis, geodesic, lie-derivative

Apply flow of $V$ to a segment of a curve, look at the velocity of the resulting new curve, a perturbation of the original curve. How is the new velocity (tangent) related to the original one (right at the start of the flow)?

Precisely:

Fix a smooth curve   $\gamma$ on a manifold $M$; and a vector field $V$  defined in an open neighborhood $U \subseteq M$ of $\gamma$.

Consider the flow of $\ V$, 
$$ \Phi:(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)\times U \longrightarrow M, $$
which exists for small $\epsilon$.

We also write for fixed value $s$,
$$\Phi _s(.):U \longrightarrow M.$$ It locally shifts $U$ to another open neighborhood of $\gamma$.

Fix $p$ on the curve, fix $s$. Then $ D\Phi _s$, the differential of $\Phi _s$, maps the tangent vector $\gamma '(p)$ to a vector at $\Phi _s(p)$.

In particular, at $s=0$, the vector $D\Phi _0(p)$ is again a vector at $p$.

Now, my question is: **What is this vector? Is it the covariant derivative of $V$ along $\gamma '(p)$?**

I would appreciate your shared thoughts. Thanks.

The **motivation**: This came up when I attempted to define a geodesic, as a path that has the shortest length among all perturbations by vectors along it. (The vector is zero at the two ends.)

Comment: Your construction doesn't use geometric structure (i.e. a metric or connection), so it certainly won't produce a covariant derivative. But more immediately: isn't $\Phi_0$ just the identity, and thus $D\Phi_0(\gamma'(p)) = \gamma'(p)$?

Comment: Yes! This was what struck my mind as I was finishing my post. What I am looking for, then, is a kind of $\frac{d}{ds}\Phi _s(.)$ that is nontrivial, as you pointed out. I am sort of finding it here: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/diffgeomPage/handouts/covariantder.pdf 
You may forget about this and think about the Motivation part above I mentioned. So, my question is basically whether we can define geodesics without parallel transport, or a connection.

Comment: If you're differentiating a vector field defined on an open set (rather than a curve) then you can make sense of $\frac d {ds} \Phi_s$ as the Lie derivative. As to the question of geodesics, you really need some kind of geometric structure - by changing the metric on a manifold you also change which curves are geodesics. (Without geometry, how do you define "shortest length"?) If the only structure you have is that of a smooth manifold, the only thing distinguishing curves locally is whether they are regular or not.

Comment: To address the last sentence of your question directly: it sounds like you want to derive the geodesic condition via the calculus of variations; i.e. by finding the Euler-Lagrange equation of arclength. This will give you an equation that reduces to the geodesic equation if you require fixed-speed parametrization. In particular it will have derivatives of the metric in the usual Christoffel symbol combinations; i.e. the metric connection appears naturally.